# PostgreSQL: Return a single row with window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a data set that has two level breakdown; trying to summarize over the top level with a window function (a cumulative sum) but window functions does not group output into a single row.

The data looks like this:

> date | top level a | a1 | field to summarize
>   date | top level a | a2 | field to summarize
>   date | top level b | b1 | field to summarize
>   date | top level b | b2 | field to summarize
>   date | top level b | b3 | field to summarize

I am doing:

```
SUM(field_to_summarize) OVER (partition by top_level order by date) AS CumulativeSum
```

This returns the same CumulativeSum per top level on every row as you see above.
How do I do the aggregate by window but return just one row per top level? Like so:

> date | top level a | Cumulative Sum for a
>   date | top level b | Cumulative Sum for b

Comment: Is it not just simply `select top_level, sum(field_to_summarize) form my_table group by top_level order by top_level` ? Note that cumulative sum on the last row will be equal to the sum of all values up to and including the last row in the by-group

Comment: This works if I only want a one-time running total. But I need to group by date as well, to have a monthly running total. Any other thoughts?

Comment: just add a group by top_level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Note the nested sum function inside sum()over()

```
create table myData(
date date
,top_level text
,second_level text
,value int
);

insert into myData values('2012-12-01','A', 'A1', 12);
insert into myData values('2012-12-01','A', 'A2', 19);
insert into myData values('2012-12-01','B', 'B1', 10);
insert into myData values('2012-12-01','B', 'B2', 15);

insert into myData values('2013-01-01','A', 'A1', 10);
insert into myData values('2013-01-01','A', 'A2', 7);
insert into myData values('2013-01-01','B', 'B1', 20);
insert into myData values('2013-01-01','B', 'B2', 35);


select 
date
,top_level
,sum(value) as value_total
,sum(sum(value))over(partition by top_level order by date) as value_running_total
from myData
group by date, top_level
order by top_level, date;
```

returns:

```
date; top_level; value_total; value_running_total
"2012-12-01";"A";31;31
"2013-01-01";"A";17;48
"2012-12-01";"B";25;25
"2013-01-01";"B";55;80
```

Comment: I was just coming up here to update that I was going to try something like this, although my method was less elegant. Trying this now. Will update later. Thanks!

Comment: Yeap. This is it. Thanks Sashikanth!